# Python Call Parent Method from child method

Tags: python

I want to call the Method `SavingsAccount.withdraw(600)` but every time I get an exception `TypeError: withdraw takes exactly 1 arguement(2 given)`. How do I fix this? Please advise.

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def withdraw(self):
        pass

    def deposit(self):
        pass


class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 500

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if (amount < 0):
            return "Invalid deposit amount"
        else:
            self.balance += amount
            return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if ((self.balance - amount) > 0) and ((self.balance - amount) < 500):
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance"
        elif (self.balance - amount) < 0:
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        elif amount < 0:
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance


class CurrentAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance=0):
        super(CurrentAccount, self).__init__()

    def deposit(self, amount):
        return super(CurrentAccount, self).deposit(amount)

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        return super(CurrentAccount, self).withdraw(amount)


x = CurrentAccount();

print  x.withdraw(600)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `withdraw` method in `BankAccount` is missing the amount:

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def withdraw(self):   # <--- ADD THE AMOUNT HERE
        pass
```

Same with the `deposit` method

Comment: Thanks a lot. Missed that